# Footer out of screen on iphone

Tags: html, css, ios

referring to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660077/how-to-fit-content-in-middle-of-header-and-footer) made by me where i was asking on how could i fit the content between the header and the footer by setting content height minus footer height solved the problem but actually when i try to add the web site to Home screen on any iPhone the footer goes out of screen as the following:

[image]

As you can see the footer is visible only in part and to see it i have to scroll the whole page down (not the central content but the page) while that problem doesn't persist on web or Android devices..

I've tryed to subtract more pixels to content height if the device is an iphone but it had no effect, i've tryed the following code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
    $('.tableFixHead').addClass('tableFixHead-mobile');
}

.tableFixHead-mobile {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 500px) !important;
}
```

But the view remain still the same, the whole css and html code you can see in the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umeq6y31/)

Comment: Does this ONLY happen when it's opened from a link on the home screen? As in opened full screen as if it was an app? Or does it happen on any iOS device regardless of how you get to the site?

Comment: @BryceHowitson if i open it throw just safari i'm unable to see the footer even if i scroll the main content while as full screen i'm able to see just a part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the goal is to always have the header and footer fixed and allow the content in the center to scroll. You've accomplished this with absolute positioning and calculations based on `viewHeight`

The problem is that the implementation of `vh` is extremely inconsistent on mobile devices. And these problems are unlikely to change any time soon (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)).

So, I would recommend revamping your layout to reduce the dependency on viewHeight. There are multiple ways to do this but `flexbox` would give you an easy solution.

Here's a minimal example of how to implement this. You'll have to apply it to your code as needed.

```css
.contentWrapper {
 /* this needs to fill the viewport
 position fixed will work on modern mobile devices. */
 position: fixed;
 top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
 /* add flex-box */
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}

header, footer {
 background-color: darkgray;
 flex-basis: 50px;
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainContentArea {
 /* set this to fill the center space */
 flex-basis: calc(100% - 100px);
 /* make it scroll */
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
 <header>Fixed Header</header>
 <div class="mainContentArea">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pellentesque nec quam et imperdiet. Nullam vel euismod nisl, sed viverra magna. Cras nec ex ligula. In laoreet ornare nunc ut pellentesque. Phasellus lobortis vehicula lacus, et tempor dui scelerisque sit amet. Cras porttitor leo a mauris eleifend, sed sodales mi tempor. Morbi molestie, est sit amet consequat viverra, lacus arcu lobortis sapien, quis maximus dui sem nec erat. Nullam blandit tellus et dui lacinia aliquam. Morbi non gravida nisl, ac viverra tellus. Donec viverra diam ut malesuada bibendum. Sed vehicula orci eu enim aliquam, ac faucibus mauris molestie.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pellentesque nec quam et imperdiet. Nullam vel euismod nisl, sed viverra magna. Cras nec ex ligula. In laoreet ornare nunc ut pellentesque. Phasellus lobortis vehicula lacus, et tempor dui scelerisque sit amet. Cras porttitor leo a mauris eleifend, sed sodales mi tempor. Morbi molestie, est sit amet consequat viverra, lacus arcu lobortis sapien, quis maximus dui sem nec erat. Nullam blandit tellus et dui lacinia aliquam. Morbi non gravida nisl, ac viverra tellus. Donec viverra diam ut malesuada bibendum. Sed vehicula orci eu enim aliquam, ac faucibus mauris molestie.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pellentesque nec quam et imperdiet. Nullam vel euismod nisl, sed viverra magna. Cras nec ex ligula. In laoreet ornare nunc ut pellentesque. Phasellus lobortis vehicula lacus, et tempor dui scelerisque sit amet. Cras porttitor leo a mauris eleifend, sed sodales mi tempor. Morbi molestie, est sit amet consequat viverra, lacus arcu lobortis sapien, quis maximus dui sem nec erat. Nullam blandit tellus et dui lacinia aliquam. Morbi non gravida nisl, ac viverra tellus. Donec viverra diam ut malesuada bibendum. Sed vehicula orci eu enim aliquam, ac faucibus mauris molestie.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pellentesque nec quam et imperdiet. Nullam vel euismod nisl, sed viverra magna. Cras nec ex ligula. In laoreet ornare nunc ut pellentesque. Phasellus lobortis vehicula lacus, et tempor dui scelerisque sit amet. Cras porttitor leo a mauris eleifend, sed sodales mi tempor. Morbi molestie, est sit amet consequat viverra, lacus arcu lobortis sapien, quis maximus dui sem nec erat. Nullam blandit tellus et dui lacinia aliquam. Morbi non gravida nisl, ac viverra tellus. Donec viverra diam ut malesuada bibendum. Sed vehicula orci eu enim aliquam, ac faucibus mauris molestie.</p>
 </div>
 <footer>Fixed Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that was actually what i was searching for, after playing around with flex-box that footer is visible now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer {
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

The above is your code. Just change from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`.

Comment: actually i've yet tryed to setting it to fixed but nothing changed, https://imgur.com/8JkSqrX as you can see here if in table there is small amount of table rows i'm able to scroll to see the footer but in case where table rows are many and i have to scroll them i just can't reach the footer (or better i can if i get an edge and try to scroll main view)

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969751/6525081) it seems that when setting `position: absolute`, you must add `left: 0` and `right: 0` properties to `.footer` in order that the `bottom: 0` will work on iphone and ipad.

Didn't test it myself yet, but it was upvoted so i guess someone else found that useful.

After digging more SO's i found also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935205/6525081) that related to this issue.

Worth to mention that [caniuseit](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20absolute) shows that from version 11 there is full support of absolute position and they not mention any sort of the above..

I guess you will test it before me, hope that will do it.

**EDIT**: As those SO that i linked above (also) mention, and also following the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), in order for the `position: absolute` would work as expected, it parent element should have any position - and that make sens. 
Seems that `form id="form"` is the parent (base on [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kLqdg1b3/) fiddle), so i would add `position: relative;` to `body` itself.

Hope that will work.. Can't test it myself.

Comment: I'm trying it on an iphone 7 with iOS 13 which should have last version of safari,  just tryed to set left: 0 right:0, tryed to let it as it was (position absolute) but nothing, the footer is still under the content and i have to scroll main container to reach it.

Comment: @IgorMytyuk Does it parent have relative position? If not try this. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following snippet, if your question was correctly understood then the result is the visual effect you want to achieve. If yes, then check the dimensions of the elements and their position in the code below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display;
  flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
}
main div {
  padding: .5rem 0;
}
main {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 6rem);
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main p {
  height: 2rem;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100% - 3rem);
}
```

```html
<header>this is header content</header>
<main>
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    <p>18</p>
    <p>19</p>
    <p>20</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>this is footer content</footer>
```